# How can I use loop in order to get xtabs function results for all variable pairs?

Tags: r, loops

I would like to get the xtabs function results per all variable pairs in my dataframe (one of the variable is permanent and the other variable should be from the rest of the variables stored in the data frame).I know how to do it manually per one pair at a time but I have a lot of variables and I would like to find a way to loop it. Any idea how can I do it?
Here is an example data frame:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " category birds    wolfs     snakes
                   yes        3        9         7
                   no         3        8         4
                   no         1        2         8
                   yes        1        2         3
                   yes        1        8         3
                   no         6        1         2
                   yes        6        7         1
                   no         6        1         5
                   yes        5        9         7
                   no         3        8         7
                   no         4        2         7
                   yes        1        2         3
                   yes        7        6         3
                   no         6        1         1
                   yes        6        3         9
                   no         6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

Manually I use this line of code to get what I need:

```
xtabs(~category + birds, data = dat)
xtabs(~category + wolfs , data = dat)  
xtabs(~category + snakes, data = dat)
```

But this can be very unefficient when I have alot of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
apply(dat[,2:4], 2, function(x) xtabs(~dat$category+x) )
$birds
            x
dat$category 1 3 4 5 6 7
         no  1 2 1 0 4 0
         yes 3 1 0 1 2 1

$wolfs
            x
dat$category 1 2 3 6 7 8 9
         no  4 2 0 0 0 2 0
         yes 0 2 1 1 1 1 2

$snakes
            x
dat$category 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9
         no  2 1 0 1 1 2 1 0
         yes 1 0 4 0 0 2 0 1
```